# Why is it faster to perform an assignment than do nothing?

Tags: javascript

```js
    class Obj {
      constructor() {
        this.propA = ~~(Math.random() * 255 + 0.5);
        this.propB = ~~(Math.random() * 300 + 0.5);
      }
    }
    const arr1 = new Array(100000);
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i ++) {
      arr1[i] = new Obj();
    }
    
    function test1() {
      let start = new Date();
      for (var times = 0; times < 1000; times ++) {
        let n = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
          if (arr1[i].propA > arr1[i].propB) {
            n += 1;
            //arr1[i].propB = arr1[i].propA; //<-- try uncomment it
          }
        }
      }
      
      console.log(new Date() - start + 'ms');
    }
    test1();
```

paste this code to developer tools(or a new .html file).

on my computer(win7 x64, chrome 63) it prints 1200-1600ms.

however when I uncomment the code it prints only 500-700ms.

I don't know why it happens...

Comment: How many trials of each did you run?

Comment: "Why is it faster to perform an assignment than do nothing?" In this case, at least, it's not. The version that does nothing is faster, and that version is the one where that line is uncommented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know why it happens...

Because after firs time when

```
arr1[i].propB = arr1[i].propA;
```

has been executed, from the next iteration

```
if (arr1[i].propA > arr1[i].propB)
```

will be `false` and hence that line `n += 1;` will not get executed.

Since you are saving one operations by replacing **increment and assignment** with **only assignment**, you see a improvement in speed.